# Mysql create trigger 1064 error

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

The sql i wrote

```
**delimiter |
CREATE 
DEFINER=CURRENT_USER 
TRIGGER set_profiletype_after_insert BEFORE INSERT ON trl_translator FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE trl_profile SET trl_profile.type = 'translator' WHERE trl_profile.profile_id = NEW.translator_id
END 
|
delimiter ;**
```

The error given

```
[SQL] 
**CREATE 
DEFINER=CURRENT_USER 
TRIGGER set_profiletype_after_insert BEFORE INSERT ON trl_translator FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE trl_profile SET trl_profile.type = 'translator' WHERE trl_profile.profile_id = NEW.translator_id
END 
;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6**
```

How to solve this ? where is the mistake i do ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you simply need to terminate your `UPDATE` statement with a semicolon.

Comment: I ignore semicolons always in sql.. the problem was solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
delimiter |
CREATE 
DEFINER=CURRENT_USER 
TRIGGER set_profiletype_after_insert BEFORE INSERT ON trl_translator FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE trl_profile SET trl_profile.type = 'translator' WHERE trl_profile.profile_id = NEW.translator_id;
END;|
delimiter ;
```