# MySQL - Create Trigger Error 1064 (near 'DELIMITER ; ')

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, delimiter

Hope everyone is well.

I am trying to create a mysql trigger however i keep getting the
following error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1 
>   [Err] DELIMITER ;

The code I have is as follows (please note, the actual file is 130 lines long I have just included the part where the problem is, or at least i believe it to be).

```
/* BB Events Insert After Trigger */
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `event_insert_after` AFTER INSERT ON `bb_events`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE `bb_device` SET `latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `status_code` = NEW.`status_code`, `timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `speed` = NEW.`speed`, `driver_id` = NEW.`driver_id`, `heading` = NEW.`heading` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62465 THEN 
        INSERT INTO `bb_journey` (`account_id`, `device_id`, `start_timestamp`, `start_street`, `start_city`, `start_state`, `start_country`, `start_latitude`, `start_longitude`, `start_geozone`, `start_odometer`) VALUES (NEW.`account_id`, NEW.`device_id`, NEW.`timestamp`, NEW.`street`, NEW.`city`, NEW.`state`, NEW.`country`, NEW.`latitude`, NEW.`longitude`, NEW.`geozone_id`, NEW.`odometer`);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = (SELECT `id` FROM `bb_journey` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)  WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF; 
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62467 THEN 
        UPDATE `bb_journey` SET `end_timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `end_street` = NEW.`street`, `end_city` = NEW.`city`, `end_state` = NEW.`state`, `end_country` = NEW.`country`, `end_latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `end_longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `end_geozone` = NEW.`geozone_id`, `end_odometer` = NEW.`odometer` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `current_journey` FROM `bb_device` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = '' WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;


/* BB Journey Update After Trigger */
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `journey_update_before` BEFORE UPDATE ON `bb_journey`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.`complete` <> 1 THEN 
        SET NEW.`distance` = ROUND(NEW.`end_odometer`-NEW.`start_odometer`,2);
        SET NEW.`duration` = SEC_TO_TIME(NEW.`end_timestamp`-NEW.`start_timestamp`);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.`complete` = 1 THEN 
        UPDATE `bb_events` SET `journey_id` = NEW.`id` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN NEW.`start_timestamp` AND NEW.`end_timestamp`;
    END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Smithey :)

Comment: Which tool do you use to run those statements?

Comment: Try removing ; after the last END

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've been using Navicat to execute the .sql file, I was going to try running it at the command line though...

Comment: @Mihai I've just tried that, it said there was an error in "DELIMITER ;"

Comment: So those triggers might be correct,try each one and isolate the problem.

Comment: I found a fix that worked, I had to add "DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `journey_update_before` $$" before the CREATE TRIGGER and change the "END$$" TO "END; $$". I will post the full code as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after looking at [Mysql create trigger 1064 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900570/mysql-create-trigger-1064-error?rq=1)

The correct code is as follows:

```
/* BB Events Insert After Trigger */
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `event_insert_after` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `event_insert_after` AFTER INSERT ON `bb_events`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE `bb_device` SET `latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `status_code` = NEW.`status_code`, `timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `speed` = NEW.`speed`, `driver_id` = NEW.`driver_id`, `heading` = NEW.`heading` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62465 THEN 
        INSERT INTO `bb_journey` (`account_id`, `device_id`, `start_timestamp`, `start_street`, `start_city`, `start_state`, `start_country`, `start_latitude`, `start_longitude`, `start_geozone`, `start_odometer`) VALUES (NEW.`account_id`, NEW.`device_id`, NEW.`timestamp`, NEW.`street`, NEW.`city`, NEW.`state`, NEW.`country`, NEW.`latitude`, NEW.`longitude`, NEW.`geozone_id`, NEW.`odometer`);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = (SELECT `id` FROM `bb_journey` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)  WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF; 
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62467 THEN 
        UPDATE `bb_journey` SET `end_timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `end_street` = NEW.`street`, `end_city` = NEW.`city`, `end_state` = NEW.`state`, `end_country` = NEW.`country`, `end_latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `end_longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `end_geozone` = NEW.`geozone_id`, `end_odometer` = NEW.`odometer` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `current_journey` FROM `bb_device` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = '' WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF;
END;
$$


/* BB Journey Update After Trigger */
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `journey_update_before` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `journey_update_before` BEFORE UPDATE ON `bb_journey`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.`complete` <> 1 THEN 
        SET NEW.`distance` = ROUND(NEW.`end_odometer`-NEW.`start_odometer`,2);
        SET NEW.`duration` = SEC_TO_TIME(NEW.`end_timestamp`-NEW.`start_timestamp`);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.`complete` = 1 THEN 
        UPDATE `bb_events` SET `journey_id` = NEW.`id` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN NEW.`start_timestamp` AND NEW.`end_timestamp`;
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

I have no idea how that works, but it did. MySQL Version 5.5, CentOS 6 64 bit.

Thanks everyone :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `;` before END

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `event_insert_after` AFTER INSERT ON `bb_events`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE `bb_device` SET `latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `status_code` = NEW.`status_code`, `timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `speed` = NEW.`speed`, `driver_id` = NEW.`driver_id`, `heading` = NEW.`heading` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62465 THEN 
        INSERT INTO `bb_journey` (`account_id`, `device_id`, `start_timestamp`, `start_street`, `start_city`, `start_state`, `start_country`, `start_latitude`, `start_longitude`, `start_geozone`, `start_odometer`) VALUES (NEW.`account_id`, NEW.`device_id`, NEW.`timestamp`, NEW.`street`, NEW.`city`, NEW.`state`, NEW.`country`, NEW.`latitude`, NEW.`longitude`, NEW.`geozone_id`, NEW.`odometer`);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = (SELECT `id` FROM `bb_journey` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)  WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF; 
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62467 THEN 
        UPDATE `bb_journey` SET `end_timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `end_street` = NEW.`street`, `end_city` = NEW.`city`, `end_state` = NEW.`state`, `end_country` = NEW.`country`, `end_latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `end_longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `end_geozone` = NEW.`geozone_id`, `end_odometer` = NEW.`odometer` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `current_journey` FROM `bb_device` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = '' WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF;
END $$                    -->removing ; 

   DELIMITER;
```

**update:1**

```
DELIMITER//;
CREATE TRIGGER `event_insert_after` AFTER INSERT ON `bb_events`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE `bb_device` SET `latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `status_code` = NEW.`status_code`, `timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `speed` = NEW.`speed`, `driver_id` = NEW.`driver_id`, `heading` = NEW.`heading` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62465 THEN 
        INSERT INTO `bb_journey` (`account_id`, `device_id`, `start_timestamp`, `start_street`, `start_city`, `start_state`, `start_country`, `start_latitude`, `start_longitude`, `start_geozone`, `start_odometer`) VALUES (NEW.`account_id`, NEW.`device_id`, NEW.`timestamp`, NEW.`street`, NEW.`city`, NEW.`state`, NEW.`country`, NEW.`latitude`, NEW.`longitude`, NEW.`geozone_id`, NEW.`odometer`);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = (SELECT `id` FROM `bb_journey` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)  WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF; 
    IF NEW.`status_code` = 62467 THEN 
        UPDATE `bb_journey` SET `end_timestamp` = NEW.`timestamp`, `end_street` = NEW.`street`, `end_city` = NEW.`city`, `end_state` = NEW.`state`, `end_country` = NEW.`country`, `end_latitude` = NEW.`latitude`, `end_longitude` = NEW.`longitude`, `end_geozone` = NEW.`geozone_id`, `end_odometer` = NEW.`odometer` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `current_journey` FROM `bb_device` WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);
        UPDATE `bb_device` SET `current_journey` = '' WHERE `account_id` = NEW.`account_id` AND `device_id` = NEW.`device_id`;
    END IF;
END ; // 
DELIMITER;//
```